# Use the content of a string for a variable referencing a picture Android/Java

Tags: android, string, variables

i got this :

```
String input = "image_to_show"
```

and in my drawables:

```
image_to_show.png
```

i do:

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_to_show);
```

this works and refers to the object in drawables

can i get it to work using the string with the contexts being the same name as the drawables object

Answer (score 3):

First, find resId by name

```
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(resName, "drawable", getPackageName());
```

then use the found resId

```
imageView.setImageResource(resId);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Resources [getIdentifier](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method to get the relevant id.

after you get that id, call imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_to_show); as usual